# Why is “number” abbreviated as “No.”?

Tags: etymology, orthography, abbreviations

The spelling of *number* is *number*, but the abbreviation is *No* (№). There is no letter *o* in *number*, so where does this spelling come from?

Comment: @MετάEd Very good. Why don't you supply those two comments as an answer?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

*No* (frequently styled *№*) is the abbreviation for the Latin word *numero* (in number). Why is it also used to abbreviate the English word *number*? Because Latinate abbreviations were second nature to educated people who wrote in Latin. When they wrote in English, they carried these abbreviations over to the “new” language.

Other examples of this practice:

- *lb*, abbreviation of Latin *libra* (balance) – repurposed as the abbreviation for English: *pound*
- *&*, a stylized way to write Latin *et* (and) – repurposed as the abbreviation for English: *and*

Comment: Except that the Latin for "number" is *numerus*, not *numero*.  This unexplained explanation is repeated until it is indistinguishable from folk etymology.  Nonetheless, I believe it is correct, and leave it as an exercise for an interest party to explain.

Comment: @deadrat In Latin, "numero" means "with the number", so you could say No. 10 Downing Street ought to be literally translated "Building **With The** Number Ten On Downing Street". But we don't bother with ablative case in English, and would just say Building Number Ten. So "number" is in fact the English equivalent for "numero".

Comment: Nice try, but no.

Comment: @deadrat My opinions may change, but never the fact that I am right.

Comment: Your opinion about whether you're right certainly seems immutable.  Nevertheless your explanation of the abbreviation is wrong.  Which is the immovable object and which is the irresistible force?  A bonus point for *ablative* though.

Comment: @deadrat All kidding aside, go ahead and set the matter straight.

Comment: Kidding aside?  What fun is that? The earliest use of *numero* in English texts followed the Latin idiom of using the ablative to count.  For example, Cicero in one his interminable orations writes *et mille **numero** navium classem ad Delum adpulissent* "and they brought to Delos a navy of one thousand ships" or literally "one thousand ship **in number**."  The abbreviation, taken from the first and last letter, changed from this cardinal or counting use to the ordinal or labeling one we use today.

Comment: @deadrat So ... Building(s), Ten In Number, On Downing Street. I love it. I wonder what he does with his other nine buildings.

Comment: Are we back to kidding around?

Comment: @deadrat I'm infected with the ablative, now that you've explained it. From now on it will be impossible for me to read something like No. 10 without also thinking "10 in number". I had no idea the wide range of infections possible from contact with a dead rat. :-)

Comment: They have medications now that will cure an ablative infection.  If you take it upon the first symptoms, you'll be fine in two weeks.  Otherwise, it takes a fortnight to recover.  It's been several in number of centuries since the sense changed from "10 in number" to "10th in order", but you can try the retro route as soon as you're better.